# Scrollspy active navbar with same id

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

Is it possible to have the same id on a div and highlight the navigation link when it is scrolled on with scrollspy? I have three divs with the same id and my problem is that the active link in my navigation does not highlight when scrolled on the area on the second div. Same goes for the third one. And also, I cannot use a class on the href. My code are as follows:

Navigation code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
       <li><a href="#same-id" class="text-uppercase home-link">Same ID</a></li>
       <li><a href="#other-content" class="text-uppercase">Other Content</a></li>
       <li><a href="#some-other-content" class="text-uppercase">Some Other Content</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my code:

```
<div id="same-id">
   ....
</div>
<div id="other-content">
   ....
</div>
<div id="same-id">
   ....
</div>
<div id="some-other-content">
   ....
</div>
<div id="same-id">
   ....
</div>
```

Comment: You can not use more than one `id` with `same value` on same document file.

Comment: @all thanks for answering. is there any other way with this? I just want to highlight the link on the navbar when it is on the same id.

Comment: What should happen when user clicks on `Same ID` Link?

Comment: It goes to the nearest div with the same id.

Comment: This is not the best practise to do, or it's totally not worth doing all this. User would never really understand the actual functionality like this. Still if you want it's possible using JS/JQuery, but i **Highly Recommend** not to do this.

Comment: @divy3993 ok sir thanks a lot!